# Rails render content_type does not work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml

I have simple code:

```
  def xrds
       @services = {
                '0' => {
                        'Type' => [OpenID::OPENID_2_0_TYPE,OpenID::OPENID_1_0_TYPE],
                        'URI' => root_url
                        }
                }
        render :content_type => 'application/xrds+xml'
  end
```

But content-type returned by Rails is text/xml. Any ideas how to fix this? My rails version is 3.0.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try use (before render):

```
response.headers['content-type'] = 'application/xrds+xml'
```

http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/incubator-heraldry-commits/200610.mbox/%3C20061011221316.186F11A981D@eris.apache.org%3E